# Wordpress - Call email function in post response

Tags: wordpress, email

I have send email funciton on my home.php wordpress file and function is below

```
$("#sendmailbtn").click(function(e) {
    var dataString = $(".pricing").html();
    e.preventDefault();
    var grandTotal = localStorage.getItem("GrandTotal");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    datatype: "html",
    data: {'action': 'fahadsending_mail', 'more': dataString, 'grandTotal': grandTotal},
    success: function(response) {
        alert("success is " + response);
    },error:function(response){
        alert("error is " + response);
    }
    });
});
```

AND THE EMAIL CODE IN MY functions.php file is below where i am sending post to fahadsending_mail function but it ajax success function it alerts success is 0

```
add_action('wp_ajax_fahadsending_mail', 'fahadsending_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_fahadsending_mail', 'fahadsending_mail');

function fahadsending_mail(){

        $to = "asadkhan6164995@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Donation";
        $message = "message message message message message message message "; 

        if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message))
        {
            echo "mail sent";
    } else {
        echo "mail not sent";
    }

}
```

and response comes in success function and it alert success is 0 
and ajax post shows following
action
wplc_call_to_server_visitor
cid 
213
security
2f40c8e66f
status
5
wplc_email
no email set
wplc_name
Guest
wplcsession 
1456325128583

Comment: Whats is the problem then?

Comment: there must be `JS` error for quotation change this  `$.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function(response) {` to this `$.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data, function(response) {`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Andrew M answer:

You aren't passing `email` in `data` JSON object, so the `$_POST['email']` isn't set. It should be something like:

```
data: {'action': 'mail_action', 'email': 'email@domain.com', 'more': dataString, 'grandTotal': grandTotal},
```

Besides that you should use `wp_mail` (which is pluggable) and should end the function with wp_die();

Regards!

Comment: Ajax response comes in success function and it alert success is 0 and ajax post shows following action
wplc_call_to_server_visitor cid 213 security
2f40c8e66f status
5 wplc_email
no email set wplc_name
Guest wplcsession 1456325128583

Comment: The second line should be 
`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fahadsending_mail', 'fahadsending_mail');`  (note the "nopriv" addition) if you are using it in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is the way you are specifying the admin ajax url in your code. Instead of

```
url : "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
```

You should be able to use

```
url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
```

Also you haven't correctly specified the name of the action. In the declaration for the action above, the name would be *mail_action* rather than *fahadsending_mail*

So if you change the ajax declaration above to the following, you should be able to reach your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    datatype: "html",
    data: {'action': 'mail_action', 'more': dataString, 'grandTotal': grandTotal},
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```